# velocity.js file is there but function not working

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

I am new to this and I am trying to make velocity.js work on a site I'm building. I included velocity.js on my index.php page and I also included velocity.ui.js after I included velocity.js

I then replace all instances of animate() with velocity() like the instructions said. None of the animations work and I get an error velocity is not a function. So I am trying to learn this and so I looked at the two files I included and I cannot find velocity as a function, so how is this supposed to work then?

This is what the instructions say:

> "Download Velocity, include it on your page, and replace all instances of jQuery's $.animate() with $.velocity(). You will immediately see a performance boost across all browsers and devices — especially on mobile."

What am I doing wrong please?

So is this the right way or not?

> $('#elements1, #elements2').velocity({opacity: 1}, 900);

I used the CDN and I still get a velocity is not a function error.

Comment: Look for JavaScript errors on your page. (F12).

Comment: Yes thanks I did say I get an error velocity is not a function so it really does not make much sense

Comment: This usually means that the file was not loaded and/or correctly included.

Comment: well according to firebug both files are included and are there and I check and made sure and both files were included.

Comment: what does $('body').velocity output to the console ?

Comment: $('body').velocity
function()

Comment: Ok so clearly it is a function but then why does it say not a function when it has to run the code $('page').velocity({opacity:1});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you load jQuery *before* VelocityJS - if it's done in the wrong order then Velocity won't know jQuery exists and will bind as `window.Velocity()` instead - which needs calling in a slightly different way.

edit: For future reference, the jQuery and VelocityJS order was right, but the user functions were being loaded between the two and not waiting for `document.ready` - hence confusing debugging.

Comment: I promise you jquery is included first. But then why does it state velocity can work without jquery? if jquery must be included?

Comment: Becuase it gives a `Velocity(element[], args...)` function instead - if jQuery is loaded first then it adds a small wrapper for `$().velocity(args...)`. Can you give us a sample of the html / js that's not working and maybe we can figure it out (ps, I'm the main VelocityJS developer right now :-P )

Comment: I have an index.php file. In that file is a div (#main-one) into which I load pages with jquery `$('#main-one').load("site/pages/networking.php");` At the bottom of the index file I load the javascript file using CDN and the first one in the list is jquery, then velocity then velocity ui and last my custom js file. In the custom js file I have this line of code `$('#specs-page, #about-page').velocity({opacity:1});` that gives me that error of velocity not a function

Comment: the line of code that loads the pages must just change to load the specs-page and not the networking page but makes no difference I get that error anyway

Comment: Are you using the `async` attribute on your `<script>` tags? Or are you loading via RequireJS?

Comment: Don't know about the async attribute. Just using normal script tags and I have not placed jquery import in the head section so there is no way it is not loaded first.

Comment: I meant have now placed jquery in the head section long before velocity at the bottom of the page so it must definitely be loaded first

Comment: Does the networking.php file also have a jQuery import in it? That could explain things as the jQuery in the new file would load, and the old one would then not be valid any more - check the docs on Script Execution - https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Have you got the site somewhere I can look at to try to figure it out?

Comment: I will upload the site to a public domain somewhere so you can see how it works. Will do it first thing in the morning thank you very much

Comment: you can see the site here http://www.newadslist.com/index.php. I removed only the content I don't want people to see. The error is still there. Let me know if you need ftp access.

Comment: You have `async` on all the `<script>` tags (for velocity and your custom functions) at the bottom - which means your custom one is loading before the velocity one - why testing in the console isn't throwing an error. Simply remove the `async` from everything - if you're concerned about performance add `defer` to all of the script elements instead (including jQuery)

Comment: I only added async after you asked me about it. Before adding async I had that same error velocity is not a function. I am trying to make the animations a little smoother. I have now removed all the async and the error is still there.

Comment: Doh - you're also loading your functions.js before velocity - and the velocity call isn't inside the document.ready call - so trying to call it before it's loaded.

Comment: I'm new to this. If I put functions inside the document.ready call then I get function not defined so where am I supposed to put the call to velocity then?

Comment: If you put all the `<script>` lines in the `<head>`, but make sure your own one (`functions.js`) is last - so it's in the same order you have now (jQuery, then Velocity, then Functions) - then you put all your working code in the document.ready (shortcut is `$(function(){ ... });`) - which will be called once the page has finished loading and every script has loaded. You can add `defer` to *all* the `<script>` tags for a slight page load speedup.

Comment: I know what the problem is but I don't know how to solve it. I have a page that is injected into the index.php main div. That page has an import of the custom.js file. But if I don't have a call to the custom js file in the page that is imported there then the page content is not loaded because it needs that custom js file. So how do I fix it pls?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Glad it worked - hopefully things start making sense and you get more understanding on why things work - it can be a somewhat steep learning curve at times ;-)

Answer (score 0):

put **velocity.js** and **index.php** in same folder or ***specify the correct path of velocity.js in index.php***.
I hope this might help you.

Comment: I am using CDN and I am 100% the files are imported. The problem is I am still being told that velocity is not a function.

Comment: jQuery must be global when using RequireJS with jQuery plugins , http://velocityjs.org/